# Auth0 0Auth Social Flow - Invalid authorization code

Tags: oauth, auth0

I am attempting to implement server-side social login using Auth0, and I am stuck with Step 3 of [this guide](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols). I get a callback from the previous steps with the value `http://mywebsite/login?code=bLvc4EmsaezBp1sN&state=UXZ8DfOZeRNGy4AKD4DsaS0n#_=_`, but when I submit the value of `code` on my server to the Auth0 endpoint `/oauth/token`, I get the response `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}`.

From the examples I have seen, I think that my code is too short. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Wreck.post(`https://company-dev.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token`, {
      payload: {
        client_id: client_id, // rknvAeGruVDG3To0Lc37hMuDKsUNBBBV (too short?)
        code: code, // Sl9fF6grhgDoecDt
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri, // http://localhost:3000/login
        grant_type: grant_type, // 'authorization_code'
        client_secret: client_secret, // Shh, secret
        state: state // 123ABC123
      }
    }, (err, res, payload) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject();
      }

      console.log(payload.toString('utf8'));
      resolve();
    });
```

Edit: Since realised the error of my ways and the params have been moved to the url.

Now I get the error `Unauthorized`

Comment: Can you post your code and/or the POST body you send to /oauth/token WITHOUT your client secret?

Comment: @neverendingqs Updated the OP!

Comment: The `payload` automatically gets converted to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (and not `application/json`?)

Comment: Is there any response body in addition to the 401 from your request?

Comment: No, just ``Unauthorized``

Comment: That's weird. As per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2, you should be getting a response body similar to your first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

A 401 usually means the `client_id` / `client_secret` is invalid. Please double-check those values.

It could also mean the `redirect_uri` does not match any of the ones you registered with (trailing `/`s may or may not matter).

From [the docs you linked](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols):

> The redirect_uri must match what is defined in your settings page. http://localhost is a valid address and Auth0 allows you to enter many addresses simultaneously.

Side notes:

- The `state` parameter is not required for what you are doing here (access token request)
- Please make sure your `state` parameter is cryptographically secure for [CSRF reasons](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12), and that the `state` in the authorization code response you receive is the same `state` you sent out in the authorization code request

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your redirect URL. It must be the same as your initial request.

In fact all values must be equal in /authorize and /token calls